# SQL Server : using command prompt doesn't display the Chinese character but SSMS does

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, sqlcmd, sqlcommand

I have a table with `INSERT INTO ABC("1000", "短消息")`, I am able to execute it with SSMS but not with sqlcmd as it is accepting it and the output is [1000, J'aime] but not the Chinese character.

I am passing .sql file in cmd as

```
myCommand = 'sqlcmd  -i %s -o %s' , input , outputfile
```

I tried putting .encode('UTF-8') option but it shows the same result and my file is already in UTF-8 format as per notepad++

Comment: Since you're using Python have you tried pyodbc?

Comment: If you're inserting non-Latin characters into a `NVARCHAR` column as string literals, then you **must** prefix that string literal with a `N` - try this: `INSERT INTO ABC('1000',  N'短消息')` - also: string literals in SQL Server use **single quotes** - not double ones